# need to modify this Regex to not remove a character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regexp `(/\?(.*?)\&/)` which when I use it in the following javascript code it removes the "?" from the replacement result.

```
href=href.replace((/\?(.*?)\&/),"")
```

The beginning href value is this...

```
/ShoppingCart.asp?ProductCode=238HOSE&CouponCode=test
```

I get this as my result right now...

```
/ShoppingCart.aspCouponCode=test
```

I would like to get this...

```
/ShoppingCart.asp?CouponCode=test
```

How would I modify the Regexp to do this

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it properly, you'll need a regex lookbehind, however this should work in your case:

```
href=href.replace((/\?(.*?)\&/),"?")
```

Comment: Remember that a minimal match doesn't preclude matching the earlier part again; eg, "foo?bar?glarch&done" would become "foo?done". It's possible that `/\?([^?&]*)&/` will work better, and certain that it will work faster. Pity Javascript doesn't allow `/x` though.

Answer (score 2):

Put a question mark in the replacement substring:

```
href=href.replace((/\?(.*?)\&/),"?")
```

If, say, the character can be something else than a question mark as well (say maybe a slash is a possibility), and you need to preserve which one it is, you can use a capturing group:

```
href=href.replace((/([?\/])(.*?)\&/),"$1")
```

Lookbehinds are not supported in JavaScript regexes.